# Color Code for Fusible or Flame Retardant Resistors: Data Sheets, Standards?

Tags: resistors, safety, repair, markings, fusible-resistor

In the context of the repair of European audio and video gear, made by companies like Grundig or Philips, I come across "safety" resistors every once in a while, i.e. flameproof or fusible resistors. They are often marked in the schematic like this:

[image: symbols for safety resistors]

The actual components are often in the range of 1...10 Ohms, size 0207 (like your good ol' 1/4 Watt through-hole resistor) and they have a fifth ring that's often yellow, orange or violet.

Examples:

[image: 10]
Note: This is just a temporary fix. The replacement part I used to bridge the defective resistor will likely fail prematurely. On the other hand, using a large 1...4 Watt resistor will last forever, but it will fail to protect the unit and I might create a fire hazard. This is just a temporary fix to check if the rest of this particular CD player still works (it does).

[image: 4.7]

[image: 1]

I would like to replace the resistors with the closest possible match. However, the service manuals often don't say what exact manufacturer or type they used, and I had no success finding data sheets by some of the companies that come to mind (Vishay, Beyschlag, BC components, ...)

White or black rings on more modern and often larger fusible resistors are common in today's switching power supplies etc., but any sources with data for safety resistors with yellow, orange or violet rings would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually asking, here? There's no question in the question body.

Comment: @JYelton I am asking if someone knows, to quote my question, reliable "sources with data [sheets] for safety resistors" similar to those shown in the pictures. With details like pulse handling capabilities, diagrams for the fuse properties, DC power ratings etc.

Answer (score 5):

Overview (details and sources follow below)

| Body Color | Fifth Band | Manufacturer | Type | Material | Fusing | Non-Flammable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grey | Violet | Vishay BC | NFR25 | Metal Film | Yes | Yes |
| Grey | White | Vishay BC | NFR25H | Metal Film | Yes | Yes |
| Dark Brown (Bakelite) | Blue | Yageo / Vitrohm | BWF | Wirewound | Yes | Yes |
| Grey | Blue | Yageo / Vitrohm | RFS | Wirewound | Yes | Yes |
| Green | Brown, Black, Red or Orange | Yageo / Vitrohm | CRT | Wirewound | Yes | Yes |
| Grey | Black | Yageo | FCR | Carbon Film | No | Yes |
| Green | White | Yageo | FKN | Wire Wound | Yes | Yes |
| Grey | Yellow | TT electronics / Welwyn | FC4 | Carbon Film | Yes | Yes |
| Grey | Yellow | TT electronics / Welwyn | FA8225, FA8325, FA8425 | Metal Film | Yes | Yes |
| Blue | Yellow | Firstohm | FGE | Not stated in data sheet, maybe metal film? | Yes | Yes |
| Pink | Black | Firstohm | SCP | Not stated in data sheet, maybe wirewound? | Yes | Yes |
| Blue | Green | KOA Speer | RF25CC | Likely metal film? | Yes | Yes |

---

For resistors with a grey body and a violet 5th ring, the answer is Vishay, NFR25. Grey body with white band: NFR25H

[image]

[image]

Data Sheet: https://www.vishay.com/doc/?28737

---

Bakelite case with blue band: Vitrohm/Yageo BWF ([data sheet](http://www.vitrohm.com/content/files/vitrohm-bwf-wirewound-fusible-resistor-datasheet.pdf))

[image: bwf]

---

Grey body with blue band: Vitrohm/Yageo RFS
The picture does not show the blue band, but it is mentioned in the [data sheet](http://www.vitrohm.com/content/files/vitrohm-rfs-wirewound-fusible-resistor-datasheet.pdf).

[image]

---

Green Body with fifth band in brown, black, red or orange: Yageo / Vitrohm CRT ([data sheet](https://www.vitrohm.com/content/files/vitrohm-crt-wirewound-fusible-resistor-datasheet.pdf)):

[image]
[image]

---

Grey body, black fifth band: Yageo FCR carbon film resistor, flame-proof, non-fusible.
[2021 (current) data sheet](https://www.yageo.com/upload/media/product/products/datasheet/lr/YAGEO%20FCR_datasheet_2021v0.pdf), no marking specification.
[2020 (previous) data sheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/447/Yageo_LR_FCR_1-1947923.pdf), "gray color lacquer", "5th color code: black"

[image: fcr]

---

Green body, white fifth band: Yageo FKN wirewound resistor, fusible, flame-proof.
[2022 (current) data sheet](https://www.yageo.com/upload/media/product/products/datasheet/lr/YAGEO%20FKN_datasheet_2022v1.pdf), no marking specification.
[2020 (previous) data sheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/447/Yageo_LR_FKN_1-1947941.pdf), "green color [...] lacquer", "5th color code: white"

[image: fkn]

---

Grey body with fifth yellow band: TT electronics / Welwyn type FC4 ([data sheet](https://www.ttelectronics.com/TTElectronics/media/ProductFiles/Datasheet/FC4.pdf)).

[image]
[image]

... or [FA8025 series](https://www.ttelectronics.com/TTElectronics/media/ProductFiles/Datasheet/FA8025.pdf) (FA8225, FA8325, FA8425)
[image]
[image]

---

Blue body, yellow fifth band: Firstohm FGE. [Link to distributor for the catalog](https://www.alfatec.de/fileadmin/Webdata/Kataloge/FIRSTOHM-Catalogue-V1.1.pdf), because the individual data sheet from the manufacturer is only available upon request.
The data sheet does not state the marking code, so we have to rely on the picture for the type/series on their website.

[image: fge]

---

Pink body, black fifth band: Firstohm SCP. [Link to distributor for the catalog](https://www.alfatec.de/fileadmin/Webdata/Kataloge/FIRSTOHM-Catalogue-V1.1.pdf), because the individual data sheet from the manufacturer is only available upon request.
The data sheet does not state the marking code, so we have to rely on the picture for the type/series on their website.

[image: scp]

Note (1): Firstohm uses a blue fifth band to mark high voltage resistors. For small types like 0207 especially, high voltage resistors will have high resistance values (above 100 kOhm, mostly above 1 MOhm) while fusible resistors will have low values (below 1 kOhm, mostly below 100 Ohm).

Note (2): The data sheets are not easily available for download from their website, there are no specifications for the marking codes, but hey - if you enjoy fancy artwork instead, they certainly have some on-topic stuff in their catalog, boom!

[image: boom]

---

Blue body, green fifth stripe: Fusible resistors, [series RF25CC](https://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/RF25CC.pdf)

[image]

KOA: [Their marking specification](https://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/Appendix_D.pdf) is exceptionally valuable. Thank you, KOA Speer.

[image: koa_marking_specification]

Also, I do wish that all manufacturers had [charts like this one](https://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/brochures/KOA_Product_ID_Card_final_41423.pdf):

[image]

Note: KOA also has surge-rated resistors, they have a blue/grey body with a fifth band in black, green or white. Another example why one must check the footnotes and think about the application when replacing a special-purpose resistor. My favorite chemistry teacher once taught me that "one can do anything if one knows what they're doing". In the context of repair work: Fix anything, but know what you're doing. (And you won't cause someone's house to burn down.)

Comment: Nice summary! Don't forget the quite common "black- black-black-black-black on brown body" - traditionally used on resistors that need to be replaced.

Comment: @asdfex What? Never seen one of those during my many years of fixing stuff. Will look on eBay, and get a pack of 10 pieces in case I have to replace one. Hope they are still being made. ;-)